# UITextView and Accessibility: swipe right and left for next paragraph

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, accessibility

In iOS Safari you can swipe right or left to go to next/previous paragraph in the text with VoiceOver. How can this be accomplished in UITextView?

Comment: Hi, I'm facing a similar issue. Any update on this?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I had to set `UIAccessibilityTraitAllowsDirectInteraction` so that I could have my own gesture recognizers. This of course leads to various other problems. Let me know if you find something useful.

Comment: I'm completely getting rid of the textview option and using a combination of UILabels and Tableviews. So still on the lookout for something simpler and more direct. Folks like KNFB reader have implemented this but I can't figure out what kind of UI element they're using.